# Parsing Title from any given website

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've created a very small script in vba to parse Title from almost any website. I've checked it with few websites and it is providing with the accurate results. I used split function on responsetext to achieve the result. Websites should be placed in column A and the results will be displayed in column B adjacent to each site. I tried to make it flawless.

```
Sub Title_Data()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
    With http
        .Open "GET", cel.Value, False
        .send

        L = L + 1
        Cells(L, 2) = Split(Split(.responseText, "<title>")(1), "</title>")(0)
    End With
Next cel
Set http = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Error handling

What if there is no `<title>` in a web page,
or if it's written as `<TITLE>`?
The script will crash.

It we would be good to check the result of `Split` to make sure you don't access an invalid index.

#### Extracting substrings

Instead of `Split`,
it would be better to use `Instr` to find the start and end positions of the title, and then `Mid` to extract the substring.
This is better because `Split` creates an array of strings, and scan until the end of the input string. `Instr` can stop immediately when it finds a match and doesn't need to create new objects.

Comment: Thanks sir janos, for your suggestion. I didn't think of uppercase side. I'll follow your guideline. Thanks again.